# ¿Como saber cuántas veces tiene un texto una palabra específica?

Tags: python

Quiero saber cuántas veces tiene un texto una palabra específica. Utiliso graphlab.

He importado los datos aqui :

```
products = graphlab.SFrame('amazon_baby.gl/')
products.head()
```

Con la ayuda de [esta respuesta escrito por Fred Foo sobre SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498665/count-occurrences-of-a-couple-of-specific-words) he escrito mi propia función :

```
def awesome_count ():
    wordcount = dict((x,0) for x in products['review'])
    for w in re.findall(r"\w+", s):
        if 'awesome' in wordcount:
            wordcount[awesome] += 1
    return wordcount[awesome]
```

Y intenté ejecutarla :

```
products['awesome'] = products['word_count'].apply(awesome_count)
```

Esto es lo que pide [la definición del ejercicio](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ml-foundations/supplement/phb1M/reading-analyzing-product-sentiment-assignment) :

> you will use .apply() to iterate awesome_count for each row of products[‘word_count’] and create a new column called ‘awesome’ with the resulting counts.

Y no funciona la función, dice que se necesite llamar el input :

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-39-015c1560e4f6> in <module>()
> ----> 1 products['awesome'] = products['word_count'].apply(awesome_count)
>
> /home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/data_structures/sarray.pyc in apply(self, fn, dtype, skip_undefined, seed)
>    1868         assert callable(fn), "Input function must be callable."
>    1869 
> -> 1870         dryrun = [fn(i) for i in self.head(100) if i is not None]
>    1871         if dtype == None:
>    1872             dtype = infer_type_of_list(dryrun)
>
> TypeError: awesome_count() takes no arguments (1 given)
> ```

**¿Pueden ayudarme saber cuántas veces tiene el texto la palabra "awesome"?**

#### *edit*

**¿Y como hacer si deseo contar cuántas distintas veces tiene el texto las distintas palabras de una lista por ejemplo en selected_words=['awesome', 'nice', 'wrong'] ?**

Intenté :

```
selected_words = ['awesome', 'great', 'fantastic', 'amazing', 'love', 'horrible', 'bad', 'terrible', 'awful', 'wow', 'hate']

word = 'inicializacion'
# Quiero saber cuentas veces tengo una palabra que viene de selected_word_count
def selected_word_count(wordcount): 
    if any(word in wordcount for word in selected_words): 
        return wordcount[word]
```

---

Estoy siguiendo el curso [Machine Learning Foundations: A Case Study Approach de la University of Washington sobre Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ml-foundations/home/welcome).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que como comenta Patricio en su respuesta la función `awesome_count()` no tiene ningún parámetro de entrada pero es aplicada sobre los elementos de la columna `products [ 'word_count' ]`. Al hacer `apply()` estas haciendo que la función sea llamada una vez por cada elemento de la columna, **pasandole este elemento a dicha función como parámetro** y usando su retorno para construir la columna  `products['awesome']`. Es decir, `awesome_count()` debe tener como parámetro de entrada el objeto donde debe buscar 'awesome'.

Dicho esto, ten en cuenta que con `products['awesome'] = products['word_count'].apply(awesome_count)` **estas aplicando la función sobre una columna que tienes que tener creada anteriormente llamada `word_count`** y que debe ser un `SArray` de diccionarios. Cada diccionario tiene como claves las palabras presentes en cada `review` y como valor el numero de veces que aparecen:

```
|                       review                         |                                           word_count                                      |
|------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 'Very soft and comfortable and warmer than it looks' | {'Very': 1, `'soft' 'and': 2, 'comfortable': 1, 'warmer': 1 'than': 1 'it': 1 'looks': 1} |
```

De no tener creada dicha columna debes crearla antes o cambiar la forma en la que creas la columna `'awesome'`.

La función  debería ser así:

```
def awesome_count(wordcount): 
    if 'awesome' in wordcount: 
        return wordcount['awesome'] 
    else: 
        return 0
```

El código completo debería ser:

```
products = graphlab.SFrame('amazon_baby.gl/')
products['word_count'] = graphlab.text_analytics.count_words(products['review'])

def awesome_count(wordcount): 
    if 'awesome' in wordcount: 
        return wordcount['awesome'] 
    else: 
        return 0

products['awesome'] = products ['word_count'].apply(awesome_count)
```

Si tienes dudas sobre los métodos puedes mirarte la documentación de graphlab:

- [`graphlab.text_analytics.count_words`](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.text_analytics.count_words.html)
- [`graphlab.SFrame.apply`](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.apply.html)

=====================

**P.D:** dado que graphlab es privativo (gratuito para fines académicos solo) si no tenemos acceso a una licencia podemos emular el código anterior usando [`Sframe`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SFrame) y [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)(también usando Pandas sería posible si no tenemos problemas de memoria):

```
import collections
import re
import sframe

products = sframe.SFrame('amazon_baby.gl/')

def awesome_count(wordcount): 
    if 'awesome' in wordcount: 
        return wordcount['awesome'] 
    else: 
        return 0

def counter(a):
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', a)
    return dict(collections.Counter(words))

products['word_count'] = products['review'].apply(counter)
products['awesome'] = products ['word_count'].apply(awesome_count)
```

=====================

**P.D 2:** En el supuesto que no quisieras crear la columna `'word_count'` previamente puedes crear la columna `'awesome'` directamente iterando sobre `'review'`:

```
products = graphlab.SFrame('amazon_baby.gl/')

def awesome_count(review):
    return graphlab.text_analytics.count_words(review)['awesome']

products['awesome'] = products ['review'].apply(awesome_count)
```

Si no disponemos de graphlab podemos usar `collections.Counter` como antes:

```
import collections
import re
import sframe

products = sframe.SFrame('amazon_baby.gl/')

def awesome_count(review):
    return collections.Counter(re.findall(r"\w+", review))['awesome']

products['awesome'] = products ['review'].apply(awesome_count)
```

Si vas a hacer esto con más palabras además de 'awesome' no tiene sentido, la forma apropiada y eficiente es crear antes la columna `'word_count'` para no tener que separar y contar las palabras cada vez.

**Edición:**

Si queremos aplicar la función sobre una lista de palabras y para cada una de ellas que se cree una columna con las veces que aparece igual que antes hicimos con "awesome" basta con pasar la palabra como parámetro a la función y usar `lambda` para poder pasar funciones con parámetros a `apply()`:

```
products = graphlab.SFrame('amazon_baby.gl/')
products['word_count'] = graphlab.text_analytics.count_words(products['review'])

def word_count(wordcount, word): 
    if word in wordcount: 
        return wordcount[word] 
    else: 
        return 0

selected_words = ['awesome', 'great', 'fantastic', 'amazing', 'love', 'horrible', 'bad', 'terrible', 'awful', 'wow', 'hate']

for word in selected_words:
    products[word] = products ['word_count'].apply(lambda x:word_count(x, word))
```

Si queremos crear **una columna** en la que aparezcan las veces que están **todas las palabras anteriores en cada review** (crear una columna donde estan sumadas todas, no una por cada palabra) entondes podemos hacer algo como:

```
products = graphlab.SFrame('amazon_baby.gl/')
products['word_count'] = graphlab.text_analytics.count_words(products['review'])

def words_count(wordcount, words): 
    return sum(wordcount[word] for word in words if word in wordcount)

selected_words = ['awesome', 'great', 'fantastic', 'amazing', 'love', 'horrible', 'bad', 'terrible', 'awful', 'wow', 'hate']

products['total'] = products['word_count'].apply(lambda x:words_count(x, selected_words))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias para esta respuesta ! Y como puedo hacer la misma funcion para clacular cunentas veces tengo una palabra que viene de una list ? He escrito :



`word = 'inicializacion'
# Quiero saber cuentas veces tengo una palabra que viene de selected_word_count
def selected_word_count(wordcount): 
    if any(word in wordcount for word in selected_words): 
        return wordcount[word]` 

Pero me dice `jupyter notebook` que : tengo un problema con la inicializacion de word cuando hace el compilador `return wordcount[word]`

Comment: @Marine1 cuando haces `if any(word in wordcount for word in selected_words)` entras en el `if` en el momento que **alguna** de las palabras de `selected_words` este en `wordcount`, pero eso no significa que esten todas por lo que probablemente termines buscando keys que no existen. No se si termino de entender lo que quieres, ¿deseas, teniendo una lista como `selected_words=['awesome', 'nice', 'wrong']`, por cada palabra crear una columna como antes con 'awesome'? Edita la pregunta al final o crea otra pregunta, si es lo suficientemente importante, explicandolo bién. Saludos.

Comment: Si ! Eso es deseo una lista como `selected_words=['awesome', 'nice', 'wrong']` y su presencia dentre de cada aviso. Voy a editar mi pregunta.

Comment: @Marine1 he editado la respuesta, mira al final de esta a ver sie s lo que quieres. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta fue lo que queria ! 
Quiero almacenar los resultados en un array o una SFrame, no sé lo que esta lo mejor. Pro lo momento he hecho :

`for word in selected_words:
    products[word] = products ['word_count'].apply(lambda x:word_count(x, word))
    result.append((word))
    result.append((products[word].sum()))`

Funciona pero tal vez hay soluciones más óptimas

Comment: Eso depende de para que quieras usar esos datos. Si no he entendido mal, ahora obtendrás una lista como `result = ['awesome', 1254, 'nice', 5784, ...]`.  Creo que sería más lógico y eficiente crear un diccionario donde la  clave sea la palabra y el valor sea la suma : `result = {word:products[word].sum() for word in selected_words}` lo que daria un diccionario como `result = {'awesome':1254, 'nice':5784, ...}` lo que facilita y hace más eficiente el manejo de los datos, por ejemplo para obtener la suma de "awesome" basta con hacer `result['awesome']`

Comment: P.D :  Marine1 no me importa contestar en absoluto cualquier duda que tengas pero recuerda que los comentarios no deben ser usados para algo que no sea pedir aclaraciones sobre una pregunta o respuesta, nunca para establecer diálogos extensos. 
Dado que esto son preguntas nuevas, aunque relacionadas con esta pregunta sin duda, deberias crear nuevas preguntas enlazando a esta o plantear esto en un [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com). Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Este error:

```
TypeError: awesome_count() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

lo que te está diciendo es que `apply` se le debe pasar una función, pero que además la misma tenga 1 parámetro que es justamente el elemento al que se le aplicará la función, en el caso de `awesome_count` esto no ocurre. Tengo poca información pero tentativamente me imagino que la función debiera ser algo así:

```
def awesome_count (review):
    wordcount = dict((x,0) for x in review)
    for w in re.findall(r"\w+", s):
        if 'awesome' in wordcount:
            wordcount[awesome] += 1
    return wordcount[awesome]
```